# How to implement overriding properties policy with rocoto ?

Tags: java, properties, guice

I would like to implement properties policy in my application : i want to define default properties inside my application, and in case of, i want to keep possibility to overriding this default parameters by a config file outside of the war file.

So i define a ConfigModule.java:

```
public class ConfigModule extends AbstractModule {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfigModule.class);

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

        LOG.info("Start rocoto configuration");
        Module rocotoModule = Rocoto.expandVariables(new ConfigurationModule() {
            @Override
            protected void bindConfigurations() {
                // default config
                LOG.debug("Default config");
                bindProperties(Config.DEFAULT_CONFIG);
                LOG.debug("before config.properties");
                // // For overriding default config
                File propertiesFile = new File(Resources.getResource("config.properties")
                        .getFile());
                if (propertiesFile.exists()) {
                    LOG.info("config.properties was found in classpath: ["
                            + propertiesFile.getAbsolutePath() + "]");
                    bindProperties(propertiesFile);
                } else {
                    LOG.info("config.properties was not found in classpath");
                }
            }
        });
        install(rocotoModule);

    }
}
```

Config.DEFAULT_CONFIG extends java.util.Properties and define default properties, each parameters in DEFAULT_CONFIG is like this =>

```
DEFAULT_CONFIG.setProperty("testModeInt", "${testMode|false}");
```

And i inject in my code property with @Named("testModeInt").

My problem is, if my config.properties is not present in classpath, i have an error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Re-entry not allowed
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:142)
    at org.nnsoft.guice.rocoto.configuration.ConfigurationModule.configure(ConfigurationModule.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:92)
    at com.google.inject.util.Modules$RealOverriddenModuleBuilder$1.configure(Modules.java:152)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:118)
    at net.antoine.ConfigModule.configure(ConfigModule.java:51)
```

Which i just don't understand, where is this problem come from, or maybe this implementation is not good, another idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [OWNER API](http://owner.aeonbits.org): it supports 3 levels of properties overriding, and it also provides mapping between a Java object and properties files and other neat features.

The first overriding capability is the specification of the default value on the mapping interface:

```
public interface ServerConfig extends Config {
    @DefaultValue("42")
    int maxThreads();
}
```

ServerConfig gets mapped by default to ServerConfig.properties in the same package. If the property "maxThreads" is not specified, then 42 is used as default (the properties files overrides the DefaultValue).

The second overriding capability is the possibility to specify multiple properties file locations for the class, so the first resource found is used. This way you define an internal properties in your jar, and allow the user to specify an overriding properties file in his home directory or in /etc/myapp, or everywhere else you prefer:

```
@Sources({ "file:~/.myapp.config", 
           "file:/etc/myapp.config", 
           "classpath:foo/bar/baz.properties" })
public interface ServerConfig extends Config {

    @Key("server.http.port")
    int port();

    @Key("server.host.name")
    String hostname();

    @Key("server.max.threads");
    @DefaultValue("42")
    int maxThreads();
}
```

The third overriding capability is to specify that you want all of the above file being considered but you want the override to happen to a property level, so that if all the above
properties file are available, when you ask for the property `maxThreads()`, this will be searched first in `file:~/.myapp.config` - if not found - then in `file:/etc/myapp.config` and then in `classpath:foo/bar/baz.properties`, and as last resort the `@DefaultValue("42")` applies, then you specify to the library that it has to produce a *merge* of all the properties resources (and consider them all)

```
@LoadPolicy(LoadType.MERGE)
@Sources({ "file:~/.myapp.config", 
           "file:/etc/myapp.config", 
           "classpath:foo/bar/baz.properties" })
public interface ServerConfig extends Config {
    // same content as above.
}
```